# How do I dynamically insert Ignite UI grid for Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, infragistics, ignite-ui

I have taken this as an example:
[Hierachical grid](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/hierarchicalgrid/hierarchical-grid)

So I am trying to insert whole `html` snippet dynamically but struggling. Inserting right into `DOM` doesn't seem to work. `innerHTML` property also does not help. I have found out this [Dynamic hooks for angular](https://github.com/MTobisch/ngx-dynamic-hooks) which I've been trying to use as so:

```
<div class="grid__wrapper">
  <ngx-dynamic-hooks [content]="grid_html"></ngx-dynamic-hooks>
</div>
```

I have defined my `grid html` in typescript:

```
export class UsersGridComponent implements OnInit {
  public years = 10;
  public localdata: any[];
  public col: IgxColumnComponent;
  public pWidth: string;
  public nWidth: string;
  public singers: any[];
  data: SafeHtml;
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.singers = SINGERS;
    this.localdata = this.singers;
    this.data = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.grid_html);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  grid_html: any = `<igx-hierarchical-grid
  IgxPreventDocumentScroll
  class="hierarchicalGrid"
  [data]="localdata"
  (columnResized)="onResize($event)"
  [autoGenerate]="false"
  [height]="'480px'"
  [width]="'100%'"
  [rowHeight]="'65px'"
  #hierarchicalGrid
>
  <igx-column field="Artist" [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
  <igx-column field="Photo" [resizable]="true" [minWidth]="'115px'">
    <ng-template igxCell let-cell="cell">
      <div class="cell__inner_2">
        <img [src]="cell.value" class="photo" />
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </igx-column>
  <igx-column
    field="Debut"
    [resizable]="true"
    [minWidth]="'88px'"
    [maxWidth]="'230px'"
    dataType="number"
    [formatter]="formatter"
  ></igx-column>
  <igx-column
    field="GrammyNominations"
    header="Grammy Nominations"
    [resizable]="true"
  ></igx-column>
  <igx-column
    field="GrammyAwards"
    header="Grammy Awards"
    [resizable]="true"
  ></igx-column>
  <igx-column
    field="Sales"
    header="Album Sales in last {{ this.years }} years"
    [width]="'230px'"
    [filterable]="false"
  >
    <ng-template igxCell let-val>
      <igx-sparkline
        height="40px"
        width="220px"
        [dataSource]="val"
        valueMemberPath="Copies"
        displayType="Line"
        lineThickness="2"
        brush="rgb(255,102,0)"
      >
      </igx-sparkline>
    </ng-template>
  </igx-column>

  <igx-row-island [height]="null" [key]="'Albums'" [autoGenerate]="false">
    <igx-column field="Album" [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
    <igx-column
      field="LaunchDate"
      header="Launch Date"
      [resizable]="true"
      [dataType]="'date'"
    ></igx-column>
    <igx-column
      field="BillboardReview"
      header="Billboard Review"
      [resizable]="true"
    ></igx-column>
    <igx-column
      field="USBillboard200"
      header="US Billboard 200"
      [resizable]="true"
    ></igx-column>
    <igx-row-island [height]="null" [key]="'Songs'" [autoGenerate]="false">
      <igx-column field="Number" header="No." [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
      <igx-column field="Title" [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
      <igx-column
        field="Released"
        dataType="date"
        [resizable]="true"
      ></igx-column>
      <igx-column field="Genre" [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
    </igx-row-island>
  </igx-row-island>

  <igx-row-island [height]="null" [key]="'Tours'" [autoGenerate]="false">
    <igx-column field="Tour" [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
    <igx-column
      field="StartedOn"
      header="Started on"
      [resizable]="true"
    ></igx-column>
    <igx-column field="Location" [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
    <igx-column field="Headliner" [resizable]="true"></igx-column>
  </igx-row-island>
</igx-hierarchical-grid>`;

  public onResize(event) {
    this.col = event.column;
    this.pWidth = event.prevWidth;
    this.nWidth = event.newWidth;
  }

  public formatter = (a) => a;
}
```

I have imported necessary modules:

```
const componentParsers: Array<HookParserEntry> = [
  { component: IgxHierarchicalGridComponent },
  { component: IgxColumnComponent },
  { component: IgxRowIslandComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UsersGridComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    IgxPreventDocumentScrollModule,
    IgxHierarchicalGridModule,
    IgxSparklineCoreModule,
    IgxSparklineModule,
    DynamicHooksModule.forRoot({ globalParsers: componentParsers }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [UsersGridComponent],
})
export class UsersGridModule {}
```

Currently I am receiving errors
[image: Errors]

Is there something I can do to fix this or is it more likely impossible to achieve?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not super familiar with `ngx-dynamic-hooks`, but I reproduced the errors trying your code alright. They (at least the first one I debugged) are from initializing the column components which are looking to inject their parent Grid(token), but are instead initialized with the same injector from the containing view (`UsersGridComponent`) so it can't be found. In reality, Angular creates injectors in [hierarchy](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) so the Grid's will be the parent injector for the columns and so on. It's technically possible to get the injector of the dynamically created grid and pass it down, but not sure if that's something that can be configured through `ngx-dynamic-hooks` or if it's not supported at all as a scenario.

So I'll answer the original question with an alternative suggestion:
Angular has some API to dynamically create components, see [Dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), however it's very geared towards generating a single component rather than a full nested markup (the latter can be achieved through multiple creates for each child, but it will be prohibitively complicated IMHO). So, a much simpler path, with minimal changes to the original sample:

- Replace the grid sample component from the parent component (in this case app.component) with an anchor:

  ```html
  <ng-template #anchor></ng-template>
  ```
- in the component code get the anchor's `ViewContainerRef` and use it's API to create a dynamic component containing the grid as need. You can expose public properties of said component that can internally re-configure the grid as needed, for this example changing the years for the Sparkline column:

  ```
    export class AppComponent {
        @ViewChild('anchor', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
        private anchor!: ViewContainerRef;

        public loadGrid() {
            const componentRef = this.anchor.createComponent(HGridColumnResizingSampleComponent);
            componentRef.instance.years = 15;
        }
    }
  ```

Running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxfn7c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I might understand this wrong, but I need to render html (which actually has component in it) from string instead of creating component dynamically as in example code I provided

Comment: You use a component to define your grid and configure it as you'd like. It's nor rendered anywhere initially, it just exists as a component (factory?) in Angular. So you're creating a dynamic component directly, instead of going through a string and parsing it with the dynamic hooks package.
I forgot to leave the link to the sample, it's now added so hopefully that clears things up

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do - have an existing component. I want to render html code coming from API. For example I have <igx-hierarchical-grid> tag, I want to be able to change it to i.e. <igx-tree-grid>. It is not only the properties that needs to be changed.

Comment: I get it, unfortunately that's not how Angular rendering works - i.e it doesn't render template 'html' directly, rather converts it to `Renderer` code (the component factory). Also, a lot of it is internal, so quite complicated to reproduce the entire rendering process from string and the public API, if at all possible. That's what `ngx-dynamic-hooks` is attempting (w/ plenty of work) and yet complex scenarios need more. Need to recreate the injector hierarchy and even if it could, IIRC dynamic children don't count for parent's `ContentChildren` queries and some functionality will be missing.

Comment: That said, what you're going for can still be done with this approach. Even if you want diff components, those aren't completely arbitrary - as in you still register them explicitly. Makes what can be generated kinda predetermined and you can have a few dynamic component wrappers to hold them (like the one for HGrid here) and choose which to create based on the config from the API. Similarly, anything you can set in the Grids can be configured dynamically - e.g. config can drive the columns/data/props, if certain elements are active, etc.

Comment: Of course, in this case the API returns config, rather than actual markup, which seems like a more reasonable approach to me anyway. And you're not limiter to simple props, the dynamic wrapper components can expose entire config objects as options or, since they can have logic and access to the config service, basically configure themselves internally given direction which config to load. It all really depends on your use case and needs.

Comment: Thanks, as it seems really complicated to handle I will go with passing config

Answer (score 0):

Have you treid injecting the IGX_GRID_BASE injection token, from where you can access the interface describing the common grid type

```
constructor(@Host() @Optional() @Inject(IGX_GRID_BASE) private grid: IgxGridBaseDirective) {
}

/**
* Prevents scrolling the page, when mouse wheel over the grid body.
*/
private preventDocumentScroll(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}

private getGridTBody(): HTMLElement {
   return this.grid.tbody.nativeElement;
}
```

There is an example that we are using to define our own scrolling handler and prevent some functionalities on certain criterias.

Available here:
https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular-samples/blob/master/src/app/directives/prevent-scroll.directive.ts

Comment: Where do I put the token?

Comment: As a constructor parameter

Comment: seems like it doesn't help, error remain